# jquery mini slider, generate unique id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

hello I am new in jquery, in my website I have mini slider please see demo here: 
http://kulinari.ge/4x4/en/cars
Here I have two slider, the problem is that the slider is repeated in the second slider images and second slide images repeated first slider images, on hover. there is my jquery code, sorry for my bad english. how i can prevent this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".cars-img img").attr("src", jQuery(".img-log img").eq(0).attr("src"));
    jQuery(".img-log img").eq(0).attr("class", "active");
    jQuery(".img-log img").hover(function () {
        jQuery(".cars-img img").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr('src'));
        jQuery(".img-log img").removeAttr("class", "active");
        jQuery(this).attr('class', 'active');
    });
});
```

there is html

```
<div class="cars-img">                  
    <img src="big image link" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="img-smol">
    <div class="img-log">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="small image link" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you show us what your end result should be?

Comment: I fixed problem, please see demo http://kulinari.ge/4x4/en/cars here. thanks